# Wide range bluetooth as network? or any valid replacement?

Tags: networking, wireless, device

I was hoping to use Bluetooth as a media for a network connection between devices. I've been reading and it seems to be that Bluetooth can only cater up to 8 devices. We're talking about 40-70 devices here.. A Master and the rest are slaves up to 70 or more. Any suggestion or thoughts about this? I am aware of local area connection and internet, I just want to gain some insights on this before I start on this project.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of [scatternet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatternet) that can help you to have more than 8 device but that's probably not a good idea due to complexity and immaturity of the technology.

You can implement a solution based on WiFi [SoftAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoftAP) - there are available out-of-box solutions as well.